# Why isn't my logging code working?

Tags: python, logging

I'm following a tutorial on logging and I am trying to make some example code work:

```
log_this = logging.getLogger("Sample")
log_this.setLevel(logging.INFO)

the_f = logging.FileHandler("sample.log")

form = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s (%name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")
the_f.setFormatter(form)

log_this.addHandler(the_f)

log_this.warning("hi")
```

It only works if the following isn't included:

```
log_this.addHandler(the_f)
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Is it logged in the file when you put the `log_this.addHandler(the_f)` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a spelling error change `(%name)s` to `%(name)s`, and it works well:

```
form = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")
the_f.setFormatter(form)

log_this.addHandler(the_f)

log_this.warning('debug message')
log_this.info('info message')
```

Output:

```
2017-04-27 .. Sample WARNING debug message
2017-04-27 .. Sample INFO info message
```

Comment: This is the one.